# Hiding a form field with ExpressionEngine safecracker

Tags: php, expressionengine, safecracker

I've created a form on the front-end on my site to allow registered members to post posts without needing access to the Admin CP however I'd like to hide a specific form element from the output.

The element we'd like to hide is a tickbox that allows an item to be featured which only the admins should be able to see. Is this possible using the automated form output? I've used the following safecracker code:

```
{global_errors}{error}{/global_errors}

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100"         onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();">

{status_menu}
  <label for="status">Status</label>
  <select name="status" id="status">
    {select_options}
  </select>
{/status_menu}

{custom_fields}

  <p><label for="{field_name}">{if required}* {/if}{field_label}</label>
  {field_instructions}
  {formatting_buttons}

  {if error}
    <span class="error">{error}</span>
  {/if}
  {if textarea}
    <textarea id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" dir="{text_direction}" rows="{rows}">{field_data}</textarea>
  {/if}
  {if text}
    <input type="text" dir="{text_direction}" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" value="{field_data}" maxlength="{maxlength}" size="50">
  {/if}
  {if select}
    <select id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}">
      {options}<option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>{/options}
    </select>
  {/if}
  {if date}
    <input type="text" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" value="{field_data}" size="50">
  {/if}
  {if checkbox}
    {options}
      <label class="checkbox">{option_value}
        <input type="checkbox" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
      </label>
    {/options}
  {/if}
  {if radio}
    {options}
      <label class="checkbox">{option_value}
        <input type="radio" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" value="{option_value}"    {checked}>
      </label>
    {/options}
  {/if}
  {if safecracker_file}
    {display_field}
  {/if}
  {if relationship}
    <select id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}">
      {options}
        <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
      {/options}
     </select>
  {/if}
  {if multiselect}
    <select id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[]" multiple="multiple">
      {options}
         <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
      {/options}
    </select>
  {/if}
  {if rte}
    <textarea id="{field_name}" class="rte" name="{field_name}" dir="{text_direction}" rows="{rows}">{field_data}</textarea>
  {/if}
</p>
{/custom_fields}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could lose the `{custom_fields}` loop and hardcode all the fields.

Or you could expand on @unexplainedBacn's plan and add a test for `field_name` as well as `member_group` -- otherwise you're hiding *all* checkboxes.

```
{if checkbox}
  {if field_name == 'field_to_hide' && logged_in_group_id == 1} 
    {options}
      <label class="checkbox">{option_value}
        <input type="checkbox" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
      </label>
    {/options}
  {if:elseif field_name != 'field_to_hide'}
    {options}
      <label class="checkbox">{option_value}
        <input type="checkbox" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
      </label>
    {/options}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's something you could do automatically.

You could wrap the checkbox in a conditional, checking for the group ID of your administrator group (or groups):

```
{if logged_in_group_id == 1} 
  <input type="checkbox" [...] />
{/if}
```

Or something like the following if you had two "admin" groups:

```
{if logged_in_group_id == 1 || logged_in_group_id == 7} 
  <input type="checkbox" [...] />
{/if}
```

The specific values would depend on the ID numbers of the user groups (**Members** > **Member Groups** in the CP).